# A style gives rise to a different rendering result if given a x:Key

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

A style gives rise to a different rendering result if given a `x:Key`

I have the following Style and `ControlTemplate` for `ToggleButtons` and they work as I want it to.

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="RadioTemplate">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, when I give an `x:Key` to the `Style` and the `RadioButton` in the `ControlTemplate` inherits the Style as shown in the following,
the rendering result is different from the one given by the code above.

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" x:Key="RadioStyle"/>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="RadioTemplate">
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioStyle}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Could anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: When you specify a key, you need to apply the style only through that key , so wherever(togglebuttons) you are using the style you need to access it like "{StaticResource RadioStyle}".

Comment: In the RadioButton within the ControlTemplate, I wrote Style="{StaticResource RadioStyle}". I'd like to know why this is not enough.

Comment: I completely understand. If I give an x:Key to the RadioButton Style, I have to use it as `<RadioButton Style={StaticResource RadioStyle} Template={StaticResource RadioTemplate}/>` even if the RadioButton in the ControlTemplate inherits the RadioStyle. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) documentation:

> Setting the `TargetType` property to the `RadioButton` type without setting an `x:Key` implicitly sets the `x:Key` to `{x:Type RadioButton }`. This also means that if you give the above Style an `x:Key` value of anything other than `{x:Type RadioButton}`, the Style would not be applied to all `RadioButton` elements automatically. Instead, you need to apply the style to the `RadioButton` elements explicitly like `"{StaticResource RadioStyle}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the key when you specify one.
The Style with a key, will not get automatically  reflected to the togglebuttons.